# compare values in two different files using Shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I have two files f1 and f2

```
f1:
38139MB
0MB
0MB

f2:
2290MB
0MB
87713MB
```

i want to compare the first number in file f1 (38139) with the first number in file f2 (2290) and see which number is the greatest.

Thanks

Comment: This is easy using `head` command, have you tried anything?

Comment: i need to compare each row in f1 with its corresponding row in f2 and find the highest number ..

Comment: @KrishnaVinay you clearly wrote in question, `first number in f1 (38139) with ...(2290)`, I don't see any sign that shows, you are gonna compare each line, unless I forgot how to read. Anyway, paste your expected output.

Comment: the expected output is to figure out which value is greater and then perform arithmetic operations depending upon condition between the numbers (38139 - 2290); (0 - 0) ; (0 - 87713) ; and sum those values finally

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to this snippet code, which makes what you need:

```
[ $(cat f1 | head -1 | sed -e 's/[A-Z]//g') -lt $(cat f2 | head -1 | sed -e 's/[A-Z]//g') ] && echo f1 is lower || echo f1
```

Hope it helps